# Django, why is my jquery url view duplicating?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm new to javascript and have just set up jquery/ajax and got it working in my Django project. I haven't amended my view to accommodate the GET requests yet. My ajax functions are sending the following Request URL:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/myportfolio/add_transaction/myportfolio/add_transaction

when i expect them to sending:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/myportfolio/add_transaction/

Why is this happening?

My jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // using jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); 

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });


    $('#id_buysell').on('change', function(){

            console.log("buysell");

            var $formData = $(this).attr("id_buysell");
            console.log($formData);

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "myportfolio/add_transaction",
                data: $formData,
            });

        });

    $('#id_coin').on('change', function(){

        console.log("coin change")

        var $formData = $(this).attr("id_coin");
        console.log($formData);

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "myportfolio/add_transaction",
            data: $formData,
        });

    });

});
```

My view:

```
def add_transaction(request):
    print(request.method)
    print("test1")

    form = TransactionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("test2")
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("test3")
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/myportfolio/')
        else: 
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'myportfolio/add_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('add_transaction/', views.add_transaction, name = 'add_transaction'),
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout')]
```

Comment: Put a `/` at the start of the path to make it relative to the domain root, not the current directory, eg `'/myportfolio/add_transaction.html'`

Comment: That was it thanks. Feel free to post that as the answer.

Comment: No problem. Added it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put place a `/` at the start of the path to make it relative to the domain root instead of the current directory:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/myportfolio/add_transaction",
  data: $formData,
});
```

Comment: Isn't it the missing `/` issue at `url: "myportfolio/add_transaction",` ?